# Django - Redirect with context

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

I have a Sign Up page which takes a user's username and password and saves it in the database. If the user is successfully signed up, I want to redirect him to a 'Sign In' page, with a value denoting that Signup was successful.

Expected output on the redirected page:

*You have been successfully signed up.*

**Sign In**

**Username**: ---

**Password**: ---

So, I am redirecting from the signup to the signin page, but I want to pass a value showing that the user has come from the Signup page and is successfully signed up.

How do I perform this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/) to add a message in the first view and display it in the second one.

Or simply put an item in the session, and pop it out again:

```
request.session['signup'] = True
return redirect('wherever')
```

...

```
signup = request.session.pop('signup', False)
if signup:
    ... do something ...
```