# django redirect with messages

Tags: django, redirect

What is the best practice to avoid multiple form submission and in the same time display message notification after form submission ?

To avoid multiple form submission I use redirect instead of render

```
return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
```

But if add a message and then redirect, there is no message displayed. Here is the whole view settings:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year,
                                   publish__month=month,
                                   publish__day=day)

    # List of active comments for this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)   

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A comment was posted
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Comment successfully added')
            return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post,
                                                     'comments': comments,
                                                     'comment_form': comment_form})
```

In the view file, i catch all messages to debug

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Of course, if I use render instead of redirect, everything works fine but I still have the "multiple form submission" issue if I refresh the page.

Comment: That is exactly the right thing to do. Maybe you are not using a RequestContext in the view you are redirecting to?

Comment: Actually, it's the same view. If I use render, I catch messages normally. But nothing with redirect. Messages rely on sessions by default. That's why I don't understand why this is not working

Comment: So you're redirecting back to the same view? Can you show the code for the whole thing?

Comment: Just updated to show you the whole view

Comment: Is this not what you're looking for, Julien? Django Redirect with Context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29673951/1757321

Comment: yes, in a way, this is what I'm looking for. But the solution provided is to use messages framework. And this is what I'm doing exactly. But for some reasons, with redirect, it doesn't work

Comment: If I comment the line "return redirect..." Everything is working fine with messages framework. But then, If I hit refresh, the form is submit again... I guess there is a way to handle this, but what is the best practice? Render a different view and avoid using redirect with messages ?

Comment: @Julien I ran into the same issue. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: Actually the answer by @Rexford works like a charm. At least for me. I just don't use the messages framework, but simple write to and pop from the session.